# My VB.NET loop code doesn't work. Any Ideas?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a script to help me out filling in a MySQL table. It basically loops through every year group and set and makes a class for their subject. For Example : Year Group 8, Set 4, English would be 84En etc etc. I made it so it loops through an ArrayList and changes some variables but I can't seem to get it to work.

I don't really know what to try to be honest because I've checked over it and I don't know if I'm blind but I don't see any errors.

```
Dim subjects As New ArrayList
subjects.Add("English")
subjects.Add("Welsh")
subjects.Add("French")
subjects.Add("Maths")
subjects.Add("Science")
subjects.Add("History")
subjects.Add("Geography")
subjects.Add("Pe")
subjects.Add("Re")
subjects.Add("Tutorial")
subjects.Add("Music")
subjects.Add("Drama")
subjects.Add("Technology")
subjects.Add("It")
subjects.Add("Art")
Dim upsubjects As New ArrayList
upsubjects.Add("English")
upsubjects.Add("Welsh")
upsubjects.Add("Physics")
upsubjects.Add("Biology")
upsubjects.Add("Chemistry")
upsubjects.Add("French")
upsubjects.Add("Maths")
upsubjects.Add("Science")
upsubjects.Add("History")
upsubjects.Add("Music")
upsubjects.Add("Technology")
upsubjects.Add("It")
Dim year As Integer = 7
Dim setting As Integer = 8
Dim done As Boolean = False
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
While done = False
    For Each subject As String In subjects
        If year = 9 And setting = 8 Then
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO classes (`classid`, `class`) VALUES ('" + year + setting + subject.Substring(2, (subject.Length - 2)).ToUpper + "', '" + subject.Substring(2, (subject.Length - 2)) + "')", conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            setting = 1
        End If
        If setting = 8 And Not year = 9 Then
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO classes (`classid`, `class`) VALUES ('" + year + setting + subject.Substring(2, (subject.Length - 2)).ToUpper + "', '" + subject.Substring(2, (subject.Length - 2)) + "')", conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            setting = 1
            year = year + 1
        Else
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO classes (`classid`, `class`) VALUES ('" + year + setting + subject.Substring(2, (subject.Length - 2)).ToUpper + "', '" + subject.Substring(2, (subject.Length - 2)) + "')", conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            setting = setting + 1
        End If

    Next
    For Each subject As String In upsubjects
        If year = 11 And setting = 8 Then
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO classes (`classid`, `class`) VALUES ('" + year + setting + subject.Substring(2, (subject.Length - 2)).ToUpper + "', '" + subject.Substring(2, (subject.Length - 2)) + "')", conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            setting = 1
            done = True
        End If
        If setting = 8 And Not year = 11 Then
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO classes (`classid`, `class`) VALUES ('" + year + setting + subject.Substring(2, (subject.Length - 2)).ToUpper + "', '" + subject.Substring(2, (subject.Length - 2)) + "')", conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            setting = 1
            year = year + 1
        Else
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO classes (`classid`, `class`) VALUES ('" + year + setting + subject.Substring(2, (subject.Length - 2)).ToUpper + "', '" + subject.Substring(2, (subject.Length - 2)) + "')", conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            setting = setting + 1
        End If

    Next
End While
```

I'm not getting any error messages, the form just loads (when the code is supposed to execute) and does nothing. Refreshed my MySQL database and nothing still. Any ideas on how to fix this??

Comment: Have you put say a breakpoint in and stepped through your code?  Are you certain that it's even executing?

Comment: A few things: you should use `List(Of String)` instead of [ArrayList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). Your sql commands are identical in all cases so just do that once, and modify `setting` and `year` according to your case logic. Use parameterized queries. Collection initializers will help make your code more readable. Other than this, I have no idea why your code doesn't work. You should debug and step through it.

Comment: Combining atomic bits of data into one element such as *Group 8, Set 4, English* to "84En" is a dreadful practice.  Even worse is gluing data into query strings to make SQL - use SQL parameters always.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This point out potential errors in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concatenating numeric values `setting` and `year` into your query string, don't you need to convert them to strings before you do so, with something like `CStr()`?

Not getting an error suggests to me that the code isn't being executed, but as others said in the comments, you can soon add a 'Stop' to check that.

Also, have a read up on "Database normalisation", with regard to combining various values into a single column in the table, think about how you're going to retrieve that information and how much easier it will be if you keep it separate.